# Symfony2 Many to Many relation update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have a many to many relation that is actually made of two many to ones on a third entity.

`Domain ← one-to-many → DomainTag ← many-to-one → Tag`

I'm building a Rest API, and I want to add domains to a Tag via a specific route. Everything works fine when the tags has no association.
But when I try to add new domains to a tag, there is an error if the tag already as one (or more) domain(s).
The error is

`The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Domain. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "AppBundle\Entity\Domain" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class AppBundle\Entity\Domain to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.`

Here are the three entities :
Tag

```
class Tag
{
    …

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DomainTag", mappedBy="tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    private $domainTags;

    …
}
```

DomainTag

```
class DomainTag
{
    …

    /**
    * @var Tag
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="domainTags")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $tag;        

    /**
    * @var Domain
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Domain", inversedBy="domainTags")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="domain_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $domain;

    …
}
```

Domain

```
class Domain
{
    …

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DomainTag", mappedBy="domain", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    */
    private $domainTags;

    …
}
```

Here is the form

```
class AddDomainTagFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('domainTags', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new DomainTagFormType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
            ))
        ;
    }

    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'api_set_domaintag';
    }
}
```

DomainTagFormType

```
class DomainTagFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('weight')
        ->add('domain', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Domain',
                'property' => 'id',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\DomainTag',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'api_domaintag';
    }
}
```

And finally, the controller

```
    /**
     * @Rest\Put("/{id}/domains", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
     * @Security("has_role('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')")
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function setDomainAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $tagManager = $this->get('app.manager.tag');
        $domainManager = $this->get('app.manager.domain');

        $tag = $tagManager->find($id);

        if (!$tag) {
            return new Response('Tag not found', 404);
        }

        $form = $this->createForm(new AddDomainTagFormType(), $tag, array('method' => 'PUT'));

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($tag->getDomainTags() as $dt) {
                $dt->setTag($tag);
                $tagManager->persist($dt);
            }
            $tagManager->flush($tag);

            return new Response('', 204);
        } else {
            return $this->view($form, 400);
        }
    }
```

Do I have to remove all DomainTags from the Tag and the recreate all associations ? Or is there a way to just add/remove DomainTags ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you paste `DomainTagFormType` code also?

Comment: I've added it after the first form